# Matlab - Plotting in the same axes of guide with timers

Tags: matlab, plot

In my gui I have an axe (f1) and Im trying to draw 2 rectangles that change its color with some frequency, it works well but after the first iteration of the timers it open a new figure and do the iteration of colores, I dont know why it open a new figure.
[image]

this is the code of my button to start the process:

```
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
%%t1 = timer('ExecutionMode','fixedRate','TasksToExecute',50,'TimerFcn',@f1,'Period',.05);
%%t2 = timer('ExecutionMode','fixedRate','TasksToExecute',10,'TimerFcn',@freq2,'Period',.5);
h=findobj('Type','axes','Tag','f1');
axes(h);
i1=1;
i2=1;
t1 = timer('ExecutionMode','fixedRate','TasksToExecute',50,'TimerFcn',@freq1,'Period',.05);
t2 = timer('ExecutionMode','fixedRate','TasksToExecute',10,'TimerFcn',@freq2,'Period',.5);


colores1=['b';'w'];
colores2=['r';'g'];

start(t1);
start(t2);
%%rectangle('Position',[0,0,.5,.5],'Facecolor','r');
disp('h');
function freq1(obj,event)
% Scale and display image
%%disp('hola');
i1=mod((i1+1),2);
axes(h);
rectangle('Position',[0,0,1,1],'Facecolor',colores1(i1+1))
end
function freq2(obj,event)
% Scale and display image
%%disp('hola');
i2=mod((i2+1),2);
axes(h);
rectangle('Position',[1,1,1,1],'Facecolor',colores2(i2+1))
end
end
```

I also try to `axes(handles.f1);` at the beggining but it did the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh I solved it adding the '**Parent**' property to my figure, not sure why in my previous code work the first time and the rest dont but I think this is a good solution:

```
rectangle('Position',[0,0,1,1],'Facecolor',colores1(i1+1),'Parent',h);
```

where h is my handler.axe, my code end in this way:

```
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
%%t1 = timer('ExecutionMode','fixedRate','TasksToExecute',50,'TimerFcn',@f1,'Period',.05);
%%t2 = timer('ExecutionMode','fixedRate','TasksToExecute',10,'TimerFcn',@freq2,'Period',.5);
%%h=findobj('Type','axes','Tag','f1');
axes(handles.f1);
i1=1;
i2=1;
t1 = timer('ExecutionMode','fixedRate','TasksToExecute',50,'TimerFcn',{@freq1,handles.f1},'Period',.05);
t2 = timer('ExecutionMode','fixedRate','TasksToExecute',5,'TimerFcn',{@freq2,handles.f1},'Period',.5);


colores1=['b';'w'];
colores2=['r';'g'];

start(t1);
start(t2);
%%rectangle('Position',[0,0,.5,.5],'Facecolor','r');
disp('h');
function freq1(obj,event,h)
% Scale and display image
%%disp('hola');
i1=mod((i1+1),2);
axes(h);
rectangle('Position',[0,0,1,1],'Facecolor',colores1(i1+1),'Parent',h);
end
function freq2(obj,event,h)
% Scale and display image
%%disp('hola');
i2=mod((i2+1),2);
axes(h);
rectangle('Position',[1,1,1,1],'Facecolor',colores2(i2+1),'Parent',h);
end
end
```

Hope it helped someone with the same problem